# How to delete rows if equal to multiple different values or if date is equal to weekend?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to delete a whole row if the date in a certain column is equal to the weekend, or if the text "Sat" or "Sun" is found? I use a table for employees to insert their hours and then use those hours worked to formulate goals they should have met. I have a script that inserts a row at the bottom every morning and then fills the table with the relevant data (todays date, day of week formula, etc). However, with the script going on a daily basis, it also adds weekends and that throws zeroes into my calculations. I am completely lost on where to finish this code. Thank you for any help!

This is what I have so far:

```js
function getFirstEmptyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("[Insert Name]'s Timesheet");
  var column = sh.getRange('B:B');
  //method to say if value in column B is equal to "Sat" or "Sun", then delete row
```

[Picture of sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCW2v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving your script 5 weekly triggers rather than one daily trigger as the cleaner solution to your issue.

(Weekly on Monday)
(Weekly on Tuesday)
(Weekly on Wednesday)
(Weekly on Thursday)
(Weekly on Friday)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of that. I will definitely set that up and see if maybe In can find a programmable way as I get more advanced. Thanks!